# Permission denied (euid=5000(vmail) egid=5000(vmail) missing +w perm: /var/mail, euid is not dir owner)

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody help me with this error :

```
Jun  2 18:22:01 fway dovecot: auth: mysql: Connected to localhost (mailserver)
Jun  2 18:22:03 fway dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<root@fway.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=220.111.215.122, lip=192.168.11.21, mpid=19889, TLS
Jun  2 18:22:03 fway dovecot: pop3(root@fway.com): Error: user root@fway.com: Initialization failed: Initializing mail storage from mail_location setting failed: mkdir(/var/mail/fway.com/root) failed: Permission denied (euid=5000(vmail) egid=5000(vmail) missing +w perm: /var/mail, euid is not dir owner)
Jun  2 18:22:03 fway dovecot: pop3(root@fway.com): Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

[image: error]

Comment: Pay attention to line 3, you can modify file permissions and try again

Comment: Has been tried 、chmod -R 777